# Products showing up in layered navigation after saving them again from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, navigation, filtered-nav

**This is Very weird problem i am into right now, Its a clothing store where i have uploaded 50 products for an example and they are successfully visible in both front and back end.
Now if i apply layered navigation filters on them for I.E BRAND name they are not visible under there brand name. So when i go back in admin panel and just open the product and save it without any changes and refresh the front end it is visible to all. I am not able to understand why i have to save them from back end again to see them in filters list. I am  using amasty layered navigation plugin
Please help.**

Comment: Please reindex , and clear cache & check.

Comment: i have done all that cleared the cache for the amasty extension also.

Comment: there is an another error like after filtering there are four products as  results on page and few filters are showing attribute value of total of 3 products where is the fourth product on those attributes.